# Using a single select statment to get the next row from a table or return the first row if the end of table is reached

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table say STAFF like below:

```
STAFF_NAME
============
ALEX
BERNARD
CARL
DOMINIC
EMMA
```

Now, I want to write a stored function with a single argument. E.g. `GET_NEXT_STAFF(CURRENT_STAFF).`

The input and output should be like:

```
Input   |   Output
=====================
NULL    | ALEX
ALEX    | BERNARD
BERNARD | CARL
EMMA    | ALEX (Start from the beginning of the table again)
```

I know how to handle this problem using PL/SQL, but is it possible to deal with this problem with a single select statement?

Comment: Do you assume the staff name encodes the ordering as well? (Perhaps alphabetically?) Or do you have some other order in mind, perhaps encoded in a different column? (Or do you think orders in a table are naturally ordered? You do know that's not true, right? There is no "natural" order of rows in a table.)

Comment: The records may not be sorted, but I can make it so if this is necessary.

Comment: ?? What do you mean by "NEXT" staff then, if the records are not sorted? "NEXT" is an order-based concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution below, I assume the rows are ordered alphabetically by names. They may be ordered by another column in the same table (for example by hire date, or by salary, etc. - it doesn't matter) - then the name of that column should be used in the ORDER BY clause of the two analytic functions.

The input name is passed in as a bind variable, `:input_staff_name`. The solution uses pure SQL, with no need for functions (PL/SQL), but if you must make it into a function, you can adapt it easily.

**Edit**: In my original answer I missed the required behavior when the input is `null`. The last line of code (excluding the semicolon) takes care of that. As written currently, the query returns ALEX (or in general the first value in the table) when the input is `null`, and it returns no rows when the input is not null and not in the table. If instead the requirement is to return the first name when the input is `null` or not found in the table, then it can be accommodated easily by removing `and :input_staff_name is null` from the last line.

```
with
     tbl ( staff_name ) as (
       select 'ALEX'    from dual union all
       select 'BERNARD' from dual union all
       select 'CARL'    from dual union all
       select 'DOMINIC' from dual union all
       select 'EMMA'    from dual
     ),
     prep ( staff_name, next_name, first_name ) as (
       select staff_name, 
              lead(staff_name)         over (order by staff_name),
              first_value (staff_name) over (order by staff_name)
       from   tbl
     )
select nvl(next_name, first_name) as next_staff_name
from   prep
where  staff_name = :input_staff_name 
   or  (next_name is null and :input_staff_name is null)
;
```

Comment: As `:input_staff_name` can be null, can you help improve your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the "output table". I added a line of code at the end, which will take care of the `NULL` input. Note: In that last line of code, you can delete "and :input_staff_name is null" - and just keep "or next_name is null"  In that case, the output will be ALEX whenever the input is either NULL or any string not found in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @mathguy I have made a few changes that seem to work. I have added the follow

```
UNION ALL
 SELECT NULL
   FROM DUAL
```

and

`WHERE NVL (staff_name, 'X') = NVL (NULL, 'X');`

The full code

```
WITH tbl (staff_name) AS
    (SELECT 'ALEX' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'BERNARD' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'CARL' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'DOMINIC' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'EMMA' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT NULL
       FROM DUAL),
 prep (staff_name,
       next_name,
       first_name,
       last_name) AS
    (SELECT staff_name,
            LEAD (staff_name) OVER (ORDER BY staff_name),
            FIRST_VALUE (staff_name) OVER (ORDER BY staff_name),
            LAG (staff_name) OVER (ORDER BY staff_name)
       FROM tbl) 
SELECT NVL (next_name, first_name) AS next_staff_name
  FROM prep
 WHERE NVL (staff_name, 'X') = NVL (:input_staff_name, 'X');
```

Comment: You are guessing that if the input is NULL, the result should be ALEX. That is not an obvious choice. I just asked the OP for clarification in that case (as well as when the input is ROSE, for example - a name not found in the table).

Comment: The OP has stated in his example that when input is `NULL` then the output should be `ALEX` so yes I assumed that it should return the first name when input is `NULL`

Comment: No, the OP did not say that. The OP said when the end is reached the first row should be returned. In the example, if the input is EMMA then the result should be ALEX. (Shown very clearly on the example table!) There is no mention of what to do when the -INPUT- is NULL (not the RESULT!)

Comment: It is shown in the example table that input NULL should give output ALEX. It is the first row of the table.

Comment: OH...  You are right, I missed it. I must have my eyes checked, I looked at that table several times and I still didn't see it. I see it now!